# Breeze navigation properties not loaded

Tags: c#, javascript, breeze

I have the following many to many model between `Project` and `UserProfile` entities. As many to many relationships is not supported in Breeze yet, I am exposing the middle entity `ProjectMember` as well. So the server side code looks like the following:

```
public class Project
{
   public int ProjectId { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectMember
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

The metadata returned from the server seems to be the right one:

[image]

The navigation property seem to be properly sent out by the server.

When I request a project from the client by doing:

```
var query = entityQuery.from("Projects")
                       .where('projectId', '==', projectId)
                       .expand("projectMembers");
```

The returned JSon data is the one expected:

[image]

However, the `Project.ProjectMembers` navigation property is not properly constructed on the client side as you see from the screenshot below:

[image]

I went through the tutorials, the breeze documentation, the SO questions related to navigation properties and I still don't see what I am doing wrong.

**Question:**
Given the information above, why is Breeze not loading the `ProjectMembers` navigation property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by checking the EntityManager's metadataStore to make sure that the ProjectMember entityType can be found.  You can do this after your first query via

```
var projectMemberType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("ProjectMember");
```

If the projectMemberType is not found then the problem has to do with the metadata not being brought down correctly.

Another possibility, have you defined a key for the ProjectMember type ( presumably a two part key)?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay! Your answer helped me review my metadata and you are rigth, it was wrong. The model I am using on the server is a Many to Many and I made a mistake with the fluent API

Comment: Please mark this question as 'answered', otherwise I keep going back to check :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mark it :) Again, thank you. You guys have built an awesome framework!